# Cyclic Redundancy Check Codewords Finding the Original Message

Tags: hamming-code, crc

So I have the received transmitted message in polynomial form as 
$$T'(X) = X^{15}+X^{13}+X^8+X^7+X^4+X^3$$ 
and the error polynomial as 
$$E(X) = X^{16}+X^{13}+X^3$$
 and the generator polynomial as 
$$G(X) = X^4+X^3+X+1.$$

I am trying to find $T$ before it is transmitted. It is my understanding that the received transmitted message is the original codeword transmitted ($T$) plus the error polynomial ($E$), but in this case $T'$ is less than $E$, so when I subtract to find $T$, I get a negative polynomial. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do arithmetic modulo 2. Modulo 2, $-1$ is the same as $+1$.

Comment: Is this the same as XOR?

Comment: Yes, the same thing.

Comment: Can you go into more detail as to why? I understand how to XOR it, but how does that add to it? How is subtraction the same thing as addition?

Comment: I recommend you review some basic pertinent material, or look for good lecture notes on CRC.